# Dynamically add textboxes and update binding as it happens

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

First this is just for testing purposes

I have a xaml page that contains only a button and 2 stackpanels
The idea is to have a class, the class will have codes and names associated to it. the codes will be queried and based on the result a appropriate number of textboxes will display. I need to be able at the end of it add names to textboxes and save the list.

Here is my current code, it creates the textboxes the way I want it to but not too sure on saving of the list once they are filled in

xaml

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackSG" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StackSG}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackSGName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StackSGName}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Button x:Name="Generate" Content="Generate" Height="23" Width="75" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            Command="{Binding Path=GenerateSGKeys}"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It connect to my viewmodel which looks like this

```
public class stackpnl : Notify
{
    private IEnumerable stackSG;
    public IEnumerable StackSG
    {
        get { return stackSG; }
        set { stackSG = value; OnNotifyPropertyChanged("StackSG"); }
    }

    private IEnumerable stackSGName;
    public IEnumerable StackSGName
    {
        get { return stackSGName; }
        set { stackSGName = value; OnNotifyPropertyChanged("StackSGName"); }
    }

    private DelegateCommand generateSGKeys;
    public ICommand GenerateSGKeys
    {
        get { return generateSGKeys; }
    }

    private IEnumerable allotments;
    public IEnumerable Allotments
    {
        get { return allotments; }
        set { allotments = value; OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Allotments"); }
    }

    TextBox txtSGName = new TextBox();

    public stackpnl()
    {
        generateSGKeys = new DelegateCommand(Generate, OnGenerate);
        StackSG = new List<TextBox>();
        StackSGName = new List<TextBox>();
    }

    private bool OnGenerate(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public class Allotment
    {
        #region Properties
        public string AllotmentName { get; set; }
        public string AllotmentCode { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }

    private void Generate(object obj)
    {
        IList<TextBox> StackSGTmp = new List<TextBox>();
        IList<TextBox> StackSGNameTmp = new List<TextBox>();

        IList<Allotment> newList = new List<Allotment>();

        int st = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < st; i++)
        {
            newList.Add(new Allotment() { AllotmentCode = string.Format("{0}{1}", "Code", i.ToString()), AllotmentName = string.Format("{0}{1}", "Code", i.ToString()) });
        }

        foreach (var Allotment in newList)
        {
            TextBox txtSG = new TextBox();
            txtSG.Name = string.Format(Allotment.AllotmentCode);
            txtSG.Height = 25;
            txtSG.Width = 75;
            txtSG.Text = string.Format(Allotment.AllotmentCode);
            txtSG.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            StackSGTmp.Add(txtSG);

            //Add SG name textboxes                       
            txtSGName = new TextBox();
            txtSGName.Name = string.Format(string.Format("{0}{1}", Allotment.AllotmentCode, Allotment.AllotmentName));
            txtSGName.Height = 25;
            txtSGName.Width = 75;
            txtSGName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(Allotment.AllotmentName) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
            txtSGName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            txtSGName.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(txtSGName_KeyDown);
            StackSGNameTmp.Add(txtSGName);
        }

        StackSG = StackSGTmp;
        StackSGName = StackSGNameTmp;            
    }

    void txtSGName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression binding = (sender as TextBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        binding.UpdateSource();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the ItemTemplate of the ListBox to display the appropriate content. Your ListBox should not bind to a collection of TextBoxes, but instead bind to a collection of Allotments.

Update the xaml to

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Allotments}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding AllotmentCode}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding AllotmentName}" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </DataTemplate
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Notice I removed the StackPanel you were using to wrap the ListBox as it is not needed. In your code you would then remove the StackSG, and StackSGName properties and populate your Allotments property within the Generate method.